# DateTimeField with field specific timezone in Django admin

Tags: django, timezone, django-admin

I'm working on a basic django application and just can't figure out a way to implement a requested feature.

I have a Campaign model linked to an Alert model through a 1-n relationship. The Alert has a DateTimeField (to represent the configured alert time). However, each Alert should be able to be set for a specific timezone.

I tried to override the save function to apply a the model specific timezone instance, but I can't get it to work in a satisfying manner. When displayed after save it will use the global timezone.

Simplified code:

```
import pytz

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from timezone_field import TimeZoneField

class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)

class Alert(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name='alerts')
    timezone = TimeZoneField(default=settings.TIME_ZONE)
    run_at = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tz = pytz.timezone(str(self.timezone))
        print("Converting", self.run_at)
        self.run_at = self.run_at.replace(tzinfo=None)
        self.run_at = tz.localize(self.run_at)
        print("to", self.run_at)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I would appreciate if anyone had any suggestions on how to make it work properly. Or direct me to a plugin I could install to solve it (I couldn't find any).

Edit:
Built with Django 3.0.7, PostgreSQL db. The records in the DB are generated as Timestamp with TZ, so I am fairly confident the Django ORM is considering these as timezone aware records.
I'm trying to get the application to render the alert dates in their own timezones in the Django admin.
So if you have 10:00 New York and 18:00 Seoul, I want the UI to show exactly these two date/times in their respective timezones.

Comment: where you want display it? in django admin?

Comment: Yes, it's for an internal use application, so we don't need to have a fancy UI on top. The basic admin is fine for our needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/):

> When support for time zones is enabled, ***Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database***, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

So there's no point in trying to convert the `datetime` in `save()` as it will always be converted back to UTC for storage. The time to convert the `datetime` is on display. Normally the timezone is the same for the whole response, so you simply [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone) that timezone in middleware or the view.

In your case, it sounds like that you want to display each `Alert` with its own localized time, in the admin. There are a number of ways to handle that. You could create a property that computes the localized time and use that in the admin, or simply pre-process each `Alert` to localize the time. But the key point is that you do that when displaying the value, not saving it.

Comment: The point of modifying the assigned timezone on save is to correct the Django assumption that the selected timezone is the globally set value (which is correct in most cases, but not in this particular use case). If I did not do that, it would save the time as computed in a different timezone than what is expected and would save an incorrect value in the db (in UTC). Your suggestion of pre-processing each `Alert` has given me a few ideas to try though

Comment: @TheMightyRubberDuck: There are two different issues here: 1) storing the correct information in the database; 2) displaying the time in the local timezone. My point was that changing the timezone on `save()` can never accomplish 2. That should instead be accomplished by changing the timezone of the `datetime` on display. Accomplishing 1 is of course the first step, but `save()` is not the right place for that either. It depends on where you're getting the `run_at` value from. If it's from a form (as in the admin) then you need to normalize the value there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am reworking my code away from handling the TZ correction in `save` and instead do it at the form level. I also felt it rather clunky. I'll update my post when I have a cleaner working solution but will flag your answer as accepted as it helped me out. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Important to distinguish the difference between naive and aware datetime objects, and also the difference between default and current timezone. This is explained very well in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects), assuming your are using Django 3.1. In my experience with storing datetimes in Django, it's best to store them in UTC, and allow Django to render the datetime in the template. There is a good explanation in those docs about Selecting the current timezone.

It's hard to say for your specific case, but I would guess you are passing in a naive datetime object and Django is setting the timezone to the default timezone. You can check naivety of the datetime object using the `is_aware` or `is_naive` functions. It also maybe helpful to share more info like the verison of Django you are using and the value of settings.TIME_ZONE.

Comment: I am quite certain I setup timezone aware datetime objects. Checking the generated database structure gets me (in Postgresql) timestamp with TZ fields. A default timezone has also been configured in settings.